# How can i Merge multiple rows into single row in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a database similar to this

[image]

and I need to convert this table into this format

[image]

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Why? The way the data is shown now is how it **should** be modeled in a relational database. For your new format, will you even know the total number of "subjects" beforehand? Is it always three subjects, for every (student) id? If not, the output doesn't even make sense as a table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pivot as follows:

```
Select * from your_table
Pivot (max(marks) as marks 
       For subject in ('maths', 'physics', 'chemistry'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query with a `PIVOT` operation

#### Query

```sql
WITH
    marks_data (id, subject, marks)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, 'maths', 100 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, 'physics', 95 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, 'chemistry', 99 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 'maths', 90 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 'physics', 89 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 'chemistry', 96 FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT * FROM marks_data)
       PIVOT (MAX (subject) AS subject, MAX (marks) AS marks
             FOR subject
             IN ('maths' AS maths, 'physics' AS physics, 'chemistry' AS chemistry));
```

#### Result

```
   ID    MATHS_SUBJECT    MATHS_MARKS    PHYSICS_SUBJECT    PHYSICS_MARKS    CHEMISTRY_SUBJECT    CHEMISTRY_MARKS
_____ ________________ ______________ __________________ ________________ ____________________ __________________
    1 maths                       100 physics                          95 chemistry                            99
    2 maths                        90 physics                          89 chemistry                            96
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when subject = 'maths' then marks end) as maths_marks,
       max(case when subject = 'physics' then marks end) as physics_marks,
       max(case when subject = 'chemistry' then marks end) as chemistry_marks
from t
group by id;
```

You are aligning the values in each subject, so I don't see why you need the subject name.  But you can include that easily as well:

```
select id,
       'maths' as subject_1,
        max(case when subject = 'maths' then marks end) as marks_1,
       'physics' as subject_2,
        max(case when subject = 'physics' then marks end) as marks_2,
       'chemistry' as subject_3,
        max(case when subject = 'chemistry' then marks end) as marks_3
from t
group by id;
```